Multiple files into single commit using PyGithub
I'm trying to add multiple files into a single commit using PyGithub.
I'm looping in my local directory to fetch all the files to be committed and then I'm trying to create a git blob for each.
Then I'm trying to create a new git tree and add into it.
Reference for this approach - https://gist.github.com/ohaval/3c183c83ec91cb528fdc4628efe2fa01
Getting exception -
{"message": "tree.path contains a malformed path component", "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/git/trees#create-a-tree", "status": "422"}

Here is my code
from github import Github, InputGitTreeElement
g = Github("XXXTokenXXX")

def get_all_file_paths(directory): 
# initializing empty file paths list 
file_paths = [] 
  
# crawling through directory and subdirectories 
for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory): 
      for filename in files: 
           # join the two strings in order to form the full filepath. 
           filepath = os.path.join(root, filename) 
           file_paths.append(filepath) 
  
# returning all file paths 
return file_paths       
    
file_paths = get_all_file_paths("./apiproxy")

try:
   repo = g.get_repo(GITHUB_REPO)

   repo.get_branch(branch="sandbox")
   
   tree = []
   
   for file in file_paths: 
    blob = repo.create_git_blob(
        content=file,
        encoding='utf-8',
        )
    tr = InputGitTreeElement(
            path=file,
            mode="100644",
            type="blob",
            sha=blob.sha,
        )
    tree.append(tr)    
   
   new_tree = repo.create_git_tree(
    tree,
    base_tree=repo.get_git_tree(sha='sandbox')
    )   
   
   commit = repo.create_git_commit(
    message="Add multiple files",
    tree=repo.get_git_tree(sha=new_tree.sha),
    parents=[repo.get_git_commit(repo.get_branch('sandbox').commit.sha)],
    )  
        

   print('Added into github sandbox branch.')

except Exception as e: 
   print(e)
   print('Git failure')


Just a tip while I'm passing by: If you know what file types you want, you can use list(pathlib.Path('./').rglob('*.py')) for instance to get all python files recursively from the current folder. or * if you want to add all files in the current directory recursively (just note that * will also include folders). No need to do os.walk() for this.

Well for starters, this code would not even run since it's improperly indented.
